# How to get right answer when using divide operator

Tags: fortran

I used fortran to write the following codes:

```
implicit none
real a,b
integer c
a=0.04
b=0.001
c=a/b
```

What i got is 39, which I can't figure out why. When I set real to a and b, they are single precision, which means it is accurate enough for this operation to get a right answer of 40.
Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `c` an `integer` (of default kind) the assignment `c=a/b` is equivalent to `c=INT(a/b)`.  `INT` is such that a real number ever so slightly smaller than 40 is mapped to 39.

What do you see with

```
print *, 0.04, 0.001, 0.04/0.001, INT(0.04/0.001)
```

?  If you really want to see 40, then consider `NINT`, after reading the [popular link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).